# How can I refer to an external definition in my SVG document?

Tags: svg, resources, external

I'm not trying to do any web stuff like CSS/etc.; I just want to create exact vector graphics for a project of mine.

Simplified, I have two files:

#### `external.svg`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<svg id="child" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <defs>
    <circle id="circ" cx="50" cy="50" r="20" fill="black" stroke="green"/>
  </defs>
</svg>
```

#### `test.svg`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<svg id="parent"
     viewBox="0 0 100 100"
     width="100" height="100"
     xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
     xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
  <defs>
    <circle id="mycirc" cx="50" cy="50" r="40" fill="blue" stroke="black" stroke-width="5"/>
  </defs>

  <use xlink:href="#mycirc" />
  <use xlink:href="external.svg#circ" />
</svg>
```

I would expect to get
[image: expect]

but instead, I'm getting
[image: result]

It appears the browser (Chrome 54) is not resolving [the `external.svg#circ` IRI](https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/single-page.html#intro-TermIRIReference).

A few of the external references I'm using are very large, so I would like to not have to deal with them (e.g. navigate around them, etc.) as I'm making other adjustments.

Comment: In your example you have test2.svg#circ when presumably you mean external.svg#circ Have you tried this on Firefox where this does work? This may simply be something that Chrome has not yet implemented.

Comment: @RobertLongson re test2: yes, I've edited the post :-) re firefox: I'll consider myself lucky that this is the first instance of browser incompatibility that I've seen first-hand. If my approach is the correct one (per standards) and Chrome is in the wrong here, I'll take that as an answer.